# Body mass index calc on flutter course not flipping colors + incorrect parentdata Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'Classes.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';


enum MaleFem {
  Macho,
  Hembra
}
int mcol = 0;
int fcol = 0;
const barcol = 80.0;

const col = 0xFF1d1E33;
const inctiv = 0xFFFFFF;
void main() => runApp(BMICalculator());

class BMICalculator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Calculadora del indice de masa corporal",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xff0a0e21),),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xff0a0e21),
       ),

      home: InputPage(),
    );
  }
}

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {

  void changecolor(int g,m) {
      g = g==1? col : inctiv;
      m = g;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Text('Indice de Masa Corporal')),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget> [
            Row(
              children: <Widget> [
                // Macho

                Expanded(child:
                  GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      changecolor(1,mcol);
                    });
                  },
                  child: MyCont(coloro: Color(mcol), ikono:IconandText(symbol: FontAwesomeIcons.mars, textu: 'Hombre'))),
                ),

                // Hembra

                  Expanded(child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      changecolor(1,fcol);
                    });
                  },
                      child: MyCont(coloro: Color(fcol), ikono:IconandText(symbol: FontAwesomeIcons.venus, textu: 'Mujer'))),
                  ),
            ],),


            Expanded(
              child: Row(
              children: <Widget> [
                MyCont(coloro: Color(col),)
              ]
              ),
            ),

            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                  children: <Widget> [
                    MyCont(coloro: Color(col)),
                    MyCont(coloro: Color(col))
                  ]   ),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.pinkAccent,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: barcol,
            ),
            ],
        ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Exception caught by widgets library
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data:

> Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
>
> The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

Can somebody explain to me which is the expanded that's incorrect please?
PS:
Yes I know there is some mistake with the boolean logic because the color of the buttons male and female aren't changing.

Answer (score 0):

`Color` should be instantiated using an 8-digit hexadecimal integer (such as `0xFFFFFFFF`)

`const inctiv =0xFFFFFFFF;`